# Reading and Writing to a Microsoft Project 2007 from C#

Tags: c#, ms-project

Is there any way of reading and writing the data from a Microsoft Project 2007 mpp file?
I have an application that reads and writes data from a Project 2003 access database file. In order for this to work, I first save the Project 2003 mpp file as an Access database and my code can then read and write to the Access database. But Project 2007 does not allow you to save as an Access database file. I was wondering if there is any other method to get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.NET Office Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905525.aspx) to work with Microsoft Project 2007.

Comment: Thanks. I had been searching google using the search phrase "read Project 2007 in code" which returns junk

Comment: Unfortunately the linked library has been retired.

Comment: It appears the link has moved here - you need Project 2007 installed to install it: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=18346 The full list of interops appears to be here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may find [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) useful. It will allow you to read from MPP files, and a variety of file formats from Project and other planning applications. It will allow you to save your data as MPX or MSPDI files if you want to read it into Project again.

Jon

p.s.

Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ.

Answer (score 1):

[Aspose.Tasks for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.tasks-for-.net/default.aspx) allows you to [read and write data to Microsoft Project 2007](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.tasks-for-.net/index.html). The data reading and writing operations can be performed easily using the simple API of this component. Also, it doesn't require MS Office to be installed on the machine running your application.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest in using the MS Project object model. I had recently developed a MS Project addin, where in I had imported / exported from MS Project.

I am providing a sample below in C#.

```
MSProject.Tasks tasks = Globals.ThisAddIn.ProjectApp.ActiveProject.Tasks;

for (int TaskNo = 1; TaskNo <= tasks.Count; TaskNo++)
{
   string TaskName;
   TaskName = tasks[TaskNo].Name;

 // more code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Project Server Interface (PSI) to accomplish this.  There is a full SDK available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms512767.aspx

Check out the section on the reporting database as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms510779.aspx

Of course, you can always use the object model, but you will see performance problems when accsesing timephased data.  The reporting databse denormalizes all timephased data into views that are very easy to query against.

Colby Africa
http://colbyafrica.blogspot.com

Comment: Thanks. I have not looked at it yet but I'm assuming, based on the name, that this allows you to access Project Server?
I'm interested in accessing the mpp files produced by the desktop version.